# R - How do I calculate the percentage of sentences containing a string?

Tags: r, text, tokenize

I want to calculate the percentage of sentences in a text that contain a double quotation mark and have written the following function to do so:

```
library(tokenizers)

quote_ratio <- function(text){
  sentences <- tokenize_sentences(text, simplify = TRUE)
  quote_sentences <- 0
  for (i in sentences){
    quote_hits <- grepl('\\"', i)
    if (quote_hits == TRUE) {
      quote_sentences <- quote_sentences + 1
    }
  }
  ratio <- quote_sentences / length(sentences)
  return (ratio)
}
```

The function works in many cases but with more data I run into the issue of having NA and/or NULL values in my sentences.

```
library(tm)

corpus = VCorpus(DirSource("/path/to/directory"))

ratios <- tm_map(corpus, content_transformer(quote_ratio))

# Error in if (quote_hits == TRUE) { : argument is of length zero
# In addition: Warning message:
# In if (quote_hits == TRUE) { : the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

I've tried changing the if statement to check for null and NA values as follows:

`if (!is.na(quote_hits) && !is.null(quote_hits) && quote_hits == TRUE) {`

But this only produces more errors:

```
# Error in if (!is.na(quote_hits) && !is.null(quote_hits) && quote_hits ==  : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

Is there a better way to formulate the if statement and/or function? Many thanks.

EDIT:

I later realized it was likely a mistake to use the `tm_map` and `content_transformer` functions to calculate this. The function worked just fine when I stored the texts in a vector and used `lapply`.

Comment: Your problem is not reproducible. In general, you could do this easily, for example if your sentences were `x <- sample(c(LETTERS[1:2], "\""), 10, TRUE)` then you could simply use `mean(grepl("\"", x))`

Comment: Thank you. I'll try that out.